# Difference between cq:include and sling:include

Tags: aem, sling

What is the difference between sling and cq includes and when should each one be used? I kinda find both solving the same purpose. 
There is this [link](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQIncludes.html) which recommends use of sling include and then there is cq doc which recommend use of cq include. As a programmer, under which situation will each of these includes be apt?

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you are developing a CQ component, I'd follow the suggestion to use the `cq:include`. The `sling:include` has some additional parameter which can come handy if you need them, but I think in my 5 years as a CQ dev, I only had to use the `sling:include` once.
See sling documentation for the parameter: http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-scripting-jsp-taglib.html#include

Comment: Thanks for the information. Googling around led me to the same answer.

Comment: I went through the documentation link you suggested, i think most of the attributes suggested there can be included as part of cq:include itself. Technically, when did you happen to make use of sling:include, can you pls elaborate, it'll help me understand better(newbie to cq).

Comment: If I remember right, it was the 'replaceSelectors' attribute. But I honestly don't remember the exact use case back then.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a component that has more than one jsp,to invoke the other jsp which doesnt match up with component name , sling include is helpful having replaceselector attribute having other jsp as a value